# How to disable tooltips for menu contribution in rcp command?

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface, rcp

I am working on a RCP Application. It has many menu contribution and commands associated with it. The application has 2 clients, one is English client and other is German client. It fetches the messages and text based upon the type of client launched from the properties file. The problem is, I have not declared any tooltips for the menu items's, but still tooltips are being displayed for them. If I launch German client, the tooltips are displayed as method declaration (eg.: create test()).
Please help me out with this.

Comment: You are probably seeing this bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=491990

Comment: That is not my actual issue. Even if tooltip text are not given in plugin.xml, tooltips are getting displayed.

Comment: Can you show some code to show what are commands and plugin.xml

Comment: @svasa : Tooltips are automatically getting added if no tooltips are provided in the manifest editor. Hence I am adding double quotes as a workaround to remove automatically displayed tooltip.